# Sending mail with Contact Form 7 gives an internal server error

Tags: wordpress, email, contact-form

Contact Form 7 keeps giving me an internal server error on one of my Wordpress websites every time I try to send a message. The error only shows up after clicking the send button other than that everything works as it should. Also before going live it did not give me any errors on my local site.

It's a fairly simple site with only a couple plugins; Advanced Custom Fields, Contact Form 7 and Widget CSS classes.

Might be worth noting we're using Googles mail servers instead of our hosts mail server I'm not sure if that could be the cause.

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Test if php Mailing works properly on your.

Comment: Internal server error is due to the ajax script. You should look your browser dev console to see if cf7 includes files are properly load.

Comment: Good idea. I checked if WordPress mail was working properly but that also gave me an internal server error. Then I tried changing the .htaccess name which worked but broke down again a couple minutes later.